# Is this application of the squeeze theorem on a sequence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

I was requested to decide if $$a_n=\frac{sin^2n}{4^n}$$ was convergent or divergent. I proved it was convergent in the following way.

According to theorem $3$ (this is how it's numerated on my academic text book), if $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ and $f(n)=a_n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=L$.

$i)$ Let $f(x)=\frac{sin^2x}{4^x}$ so that $f(n)=a_n$.

$ii)$ Consider that $$0\leq sin^2x \leq 1 \implies 0\leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{4^x} \implies \lim_{x\to\infty}0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{4^x}$$

$$ \implies 0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \leq 0$$

According to the squeeze theorem, it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

$iii)$ According to theorem $3$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0.$ Therefore, the sequence is convergent.

Is this proof formally correct? Can it be improved or simplified? Thank you.

Comment: This is not quite correct because the step $0\leq f(x) \leq \frac{1}{4^x} \implies \lim_{x\to\infty}0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{4^x}$ is only valid if you already know that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists. Instead, use the squeeze theorem to show that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Note that in your proof you haven't really used the squeeze theorem at all.  If you established $ 0 \leq \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x) \leq 0$ without the squeeze theorem then you already know $ \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)  = 0$.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Could you provide an example of function $f$ s.t. $0\leq f(x)\leq \frac{1}{4^x}$ for all $x$, but $\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)$ doesn't exist ?

Comment: @Surb Of course not.  That's what the squeeze theorem guarantees.

Comment: @Surb My point was that the OP was implicitly using the more general (false) proposition that if $f(x) \leq g(x) \leq h(x)$ then $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x)  \leq \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} h(x) $ which doesn't make sense if the limits don't exist.

Comment: The point is: anytime you use the notation $\lim$ you must *first* have a justification that the limit exists. In this case the justification is the squeeze theorem, but the OP only applied the squeeze theorem afterward.  The basic idea, though, is correct.

Comment: What @JairTaylor is saying is correct, I assumed the limit existed without proving it. Would you mind telling me how to use the squeeze theorem to show that the limit actually exists in the first place?

Comment: @Lafinur Pooya's answer below is correct.

Comment: On another confussion, I can't find any formal enunciation of the theorem that requires that the limit actually exists, though it only makes sense that it should! For example, on the Wikipedia page of the Squeeze Theorem, it only says that if $g(x)\leq f(x) \leq h(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}g(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=L$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$. The condition "provided that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists" never appears.

Comment: @Lafinur Writing $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ implicitly means "the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists and is equal to $L$."  That's why you can't refer to $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ unless you know already that it exists.

Comment: The hypotheses of the squeeze theorem doesn't require that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists - the point is that the squeeze theorem proves just that.

Comment: @JairTaylor now I see what you meant. Of course. Thank you Jair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite your proof, starting form $ 0 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant \frac{1}{4^x}$, as the following.

> Since $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} 0 = 0 $ and $ \lim_{x \rightarrow
> > \infty} \frac{1}{4^x} = 0$, it follows from the [squeeze
>   theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) that
>   $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0$.

Then the proof continues as you wrote in $iii)$.

Comment: Thanks Pooya, this seems to be right.